# iOS: How read playing a real-time music?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, audio

I would like to create an audio visualizer, and I had a question:

How can I get the part of the music that plays at a time on the device?

P.S. Example "[aurioTouch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html)" similar to what is necessary, but it processes sound from a microphone, and I needed from the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do things with real time audio, then you should have a look at [Core Audio](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/WhatisCoreAudio/WhatisCoreAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003577-CH3-SW1)